# Using babel to transpile two files where one of the files is imported in the other

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a `server.js` and a `database.js` file.

Server imports from database.js like so:

```
import * as DataBase from "./database";
...
```

After transpiling with babel with this command: `babel database.js server.js --out-file server.compiled.js`

I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
...
```

I'm assuming this is because the transpiled server.js still tried to import the untranspiled `database.js`

I believe I'm just not understanding how to do this.
How can I use babel to transpile `database.js` and import that version in the transpiled version of `server.js` ?

Comment: Why are backend javascript files being transpiled?

Comment: I'm deploying them with a react client and serving the frontend from express like so: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was a bundling issue. Solved it using webpack

Comment: May you either expand on the answer, to help others, or close the question?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this command on your package.json file

```
babel server.js --out-file server.compiled.js
```